# Reference Behaviour in C++

Tags: c++, reference

Can I confirm with stackoverflow what I understand about reference in C++ is correct.

Let's say we have

```
vector<int> a;
// add some value in a
vector<int> b = a; // 1. this will result another exact copy of inclusive of a's item to be copied in b right?
vector<int> &c = a;  // 2. c will reference a right? c and a both "point"/reference to a copy of vector list right?
vector<int> &d = c; // 3. d will reference c or/and a right? now a, c, d all reference to the same copy of variable 
vector<int> e = d;  // 4. e will copy a new set of list from d right (or you can say a or c)?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You're correct, `b` is a distinct copy of `a`, `a/c/d` are all the same thing, just accessible via different names.

And `e` is a copy of `a/c/d`.

If you duplicate that code using the `int` type rather than a vector, you can see by the addresses what's happening under the covers:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a = 7, b = a, &c = a, &d = a, e = d;

    std::cout << "a @ " << &a << '\n';
    std::cout << "b @ " << &b << '\n';
    std::cout << "c @ " << &c << '\n';
    std::cout << "d @ " << &d << '\n';
    std::cout << "e @ " << &e << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The output of that is:

```
a @ 0xbfaff524
b @ 0xbfaff520
c @ 0xbfaff524
d @ 0xbfaff524
e @ 0xbfaff51c
```

and you can see that `a`, `c` and `d` all have the same address while `b` and `e` are distinct.

Comment: can i also check adding constant under const vector<int> a; vector<int> b = a; b will copy just fine right?

Comment: @henry, sure, you should find that anything you add to `a/c/d` will be reflected in all three, same as if you set a to 42 in the above code, it would "set" `c` and `d` as well. That's because there's not three things, just _one_ thing known by three _names._ A rose by any other name is still that exact same rose, to misquote the bard.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, looks right.

If you add elements to `c` or `d`, the new elements will also be reflected in `a`.
If you add elements to `e`, then **only** `e` will have them.